# network error: connection refused after killing one process I guess

Tags: 14.04, ssh, putty

I started ssh tunnel process with supervisor.

Then I wanted to find out which is that process and to kill it. Did not know how to identify so killed one by one to find out does my tunnel still work.

I ran

```
ps -A | grep sshd
```

then kill couple of the proceses in the result.

After like second time, when I open putty and try to connect, I cannot even enter the login name - it throws message "network error: connection refused"

How to fix it? And how should I have identified which is my tunnel started with supervisor program?

**Update.**

At some point I ran command

```
sudo stop ssh
```

To check if then my tunnel will stop working. But tunnel still worked after this command. If that has something to do with the question.

I also tried pinging to that server and I see that I get replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Co-worker connected to digital ocean and started ssh service and this fixed the problem